# Right-angled isosceles triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

If a right-angled triangle is isosceles then the other two angles must be equal to $45^\circ$ ?

Is this always the case or are there other possible right-angled isosceles triangles?

Comment: Are you asking for an answer solely in terms of Euclidean geometry? It would be worth considering if the same rules apply to, say, hyperbolic geometry and other non-Euclidean geometries. For example: you may find this lecture by [njwildberger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=944aKfLHMpU) about isosceles triangles in hyperbolic geometry interesting. Perhaps someone else here can address the non-Euclidean cases for you.

Comment: could be a little bit too much for my current level Graeme: nice to have your comment/reference included in this post in case it is viewed by more knowledgeable folks in the future

Comment: No problem, whytheq. Glad you think that it's a nice addition to have included in the post. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Isosceles_Triangle_has_Two_Equal_Angles), we know in isosceles triangles, the angles at the base are equal to each other.

If each is $\theta,2\theta<180^\circ$ as the other angle $>0$

$\implies \theta<90^\circ$

So, the other unequal angle $=90^\circ$ and we have $90^\circ+2\theta=180^\circ$

Comment: +1 thanks: here is something for you to have a chuckle about [LOOK AT BEST ANSWER HERE](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080625054518AANd6kb)

Comment: @whytheq, have you understood my method ?  Then how 30-60-90 can be isosceles?

Comment: 30-60-90 CANNOT be isosceles ... I knew this as soon as I read that ridiculous post but I could not prove it in a rigorous manner - hence my question on stackexchange. I just thought you might find that answer funny.(I understand your proof and i like it)

Comment: @whytheq, I think we need to be a little careful while gathering knowledge from arbitrary sites. This is where moderation comes into play.

Comment: The link in your first line is now deleted.

Comment: @user103816, The deleted page redirects to https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Isosceles_Triangle_has_Two_Equal_Angles

Answer (score 1):

[image]In a right angle triangle two sides which are equal will base and perpendicular because hypotaneous is always greatest side in right angle triangle.
so one angle is $90^\circ$ and sum of other two is also $90^\circ$ since sides are equal so there angle made with other side is also same so each will be $45^\circ$.

Comment: Not sure about the section of your answer that says _"so each will be 90∘"_. The OP seems obvious but giving an answer that rigorously proves the point isn't always easy ...check out the answer of lab_bhattacharjee.

Comment: sorry i was writing "each will be 45"

Comment: ...had a feeling that might be the case - thanks again for help

Comment: @whytheq your welcome and thanks for mention my fault

Answer (score 0):

Here's our isosceles right triangle.

[image]

Because it's a right triangle, we know Pythagorean theorem holds true, and so:

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$$

But, this is an isosceles triangle, and so by definition, $a = b$, and so:

$$c^2 = a^2 + a^2$$

$$c^2 = 2a^2$$

$$a = \frac{c}{\sqrt 2}$$

Moreover, we know that $\sin A = \frac{a}{c}$, and so:

$$\sin A = \frac{a}{c}$$

$$\sin A = \frac{\frac{c}{\sqrt 2}}{c}$$

$$\sin A = \frac{c}{c\sqrt 2}$$

$$\sin A = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

$$A = \sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$$

$$A = 45^o$$

(Note that $A$ is technically an infinite amount of answers because of the nature of $\sin^{-1}$, but because in this case it cannot be negative, and the angles in a triangle cannot add up to more than $180^o$, this is the only possibility).

We can then find $B$, as we know all angles in a triangle in Euclidean space add up to $180^o$, and we find that $B = 45^o$ too.

Thus, all right angle isosceles triangles have two angles of $45^o$.

Comment: Your reasoning is circular because for proving $\sin 45^0 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ we use the Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: @user103816 I don't understand how that makes this circular, could you explain more?

Comment: What I am trying to say is, suppose you don't know the value of $\sin 45^\circ$. Now you'd first prove that $\sin 45^\circ$ is $\dfrac {1}{\sqrt 2}$. But to prove that you'd assume that in a righ-angled isosceles triangle the non-right angles are always $45^\circ$.